# How-to index arrays (tags) in CouchDB using couchdb-lucene

Tags: arrays, indexing, lucene, tags, couchdb

**The setup:**

I have a project that is using CouchDB.  The documents will have a field called "tags".  This "tags" field is an array of strings (e.g., "tags":["tag1","tag2","etc"]).  I am using couchdb-lucene as my search provider.

**The question:**

What function can be used to get couchdb-lucene to index the elements of "tags"?

If you have an idea but no test environment, type it out, I'll try it and give the result here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it was quite easy after I figured it out.  Please realize that the $ character has no significance to the code, my fields in this case just begin with $.  Posted the answer for anyone with this question in the future.

```
function(doc) {
  var result = new Document();
  for(var i in doc.$tags) {
    result.add(doc.$tags[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the syntax has changed, but you can construct a view to search by any item in a document's array:

```
function(doc) {
  for (var i=0; i<doc.page.length; i++) {
    emit(doc.page[i].url, doc._id);
    }
}
```